# How to Hide or Restrict the imported module functionalities in Python

Tags: python, python-module

I have two python scripts **`Module1.py & Module2.py`**

`Module1.py` has the following code

```
class Module1(object):

    import clr

    def __init__(self):
        return None

    def foo(self):
        return None
```

**`Module2.py`** is where I want to import Module1.py, so when I import Module1.py, here's what I get

[image]

so when I use the instance(module) of Module1.py, It display two items on Intellisence window i.e *clr* & *foo*, now my question is, is it possible to hide or restrict *clr* module functionalities outside Module1.py?

Comment: Depends on what the module is used for but probably not because it's now considered a new object in the namespace of `Module1`.

Comment: why would you like to do that ? you can easily rename the methods if you want to?

Comment: @Anmol_uppal, from my actual implementation Module1.py imports several modules and I feel it's ideal to hide them as the user only require to use the functionalities implemented within Module1.py.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the import to only import certain functionalities:

```
from X import a, b, c
```

You can also import the module into a protected variable:

```
X = __import__(‘X’)
```

Note: You can then define functions that access this protected variable, and return only the information you specify.

See this page for more information:

http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm